# How to receive a propietary protocol under Apache Tomact?

Tags: java, tomcat, protocols

I am addressing you with the following problem.

System: Ubuntu
Apache Tomcat 9

In my application I get data sent with the prorpietary protocol CETP:
It has the following form: Byte 1-4 'C''E''T''P' Byte 5-8 contain the length of the message. This is followed by an xml document.
The endpoint at which the message must be received must have the following form 'cetp://*' according to the specification.
If I simply try to receive the file with http I get the following error message:

```
21-May-2021 20:52:51.758 INFORMATION [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header.
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens according to RFC-7230
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:417)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

What options do I have to receive the message? Theoretically, it would be enough for me to get a ByteStream.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Must this run in tomcat?  A dedicated socket server might be better.

Comment: It does not seem the be http protocol, so you probably should not put your code in http server? What features of Tomcat do you want to reuse, that are not specific to http?